# unable to retrieve data from nested Realtime Firebse.database in KOTLIN

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am working on the application where I am trying to retrieve nested data from firebase and showing them in one card in HomeFragment, I searched through google and YouTube but never found a solution,

Here's my Home Fragment FUNCTION

```
private lateinit var mList : MutableList<all_job_details_to_show>

private fun getDataFromFirebase() {

    databaseRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            mList.clear()
            for (taskSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                val job_list= taskSnapshot.key?.let {

                    val jobDetails = taskSnapshot.child("Jobs")
                    all_job_details_to_show(
                        it,
                        all_job_details_to_show.JobDetails(
                            jobDetails.child("startTime").value as String,
                            jobDetails.child("endTime").value as String,
                            taskSnapshot.child("payPerDay").value as Double,
                            taskSnapshot.child("jobTitle").value as String,
                            taskSnapshot.child("description").value as String,
                        ),
                        taskSnapshot.child("businessName").value.toString(),
                        taskSnapshot.child("businessLogo").value.toString(),
                        taskSnapshot.child("address").value.toString(),
                        taskSnapshot.child("ratings").value.toString()?.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0,
                        taskSnapshot.child("jobId").value.toString()
                    )
                }
                if (job_list != null){
                    mList.add(job_list)
                }
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
}
```

`val uid1 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid`
       `getDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("user_business/$uid1")`
and MyDatacLASS:

```
data class all_job_details_to_show(
    val businessName : String,
    val businessLogo : String,
    val address :String,
    val ratings: Double,
    val jobId: String

){
    constructor() : this( "","","",0.0,"")

    data class JobDetails(
        val startTime: String,
        val endTime: String,
        val payPerDay: Double,
        val jobTitle: String,
        val description: String,

        ){constructor() : this( "","",0.0,"","")}
}
```

and MyAdapter:

```
class addedJobListAdapter(private val list: MutableList<all_job_details_to_show>):
RecyclerView.Adapter<addedJobListAdapter.addedJobListViewHolder>(){

    private var listener: addedJobListAdapterClickListener? = null

    fun setListener(listener: addedJobListAdapterClickListener){
        this.listener=listener
    }

      inner class addedJobListViewHolder( val binding: JobDescriptionCardBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): addedJobListViewHolder {

        val binding = JobDescriptionCardBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
        return addedJobListViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: addedJobListViewHolder, position: Int) {

        with(holder){
            with(list[position]){
                binding.address.text= address
                binding.brandName.text = businessName
                binding.ratings.text = ratings.toString()
                binding.jobName.text = JobDetails.jobTitle.toString() // access properties of JobDetails instance
                binding.startTime.text = JobDetails.startTime
                binding.endTime.text = JobDetails.endTime
                binding.rates.text = JobDetails.payPerDay.toString()
                binding.description.text = JobDetails.description.toString()

                Glide.with(itemView.context)
                    .load(businessLogo)
                    .into(binding.brandLogo)

                if (ratings >= 4.50) {
                    binding.ratings.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#318F2F")) // light green
                } else if (ratings >= 4.00 && ratings < 4.50) {
                    binding.ratings.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3CC93A")) // light green
                } else if (ratings >= 3.50 && ratings < 4.00) {
                    binding.ratings.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B1AB16"))
                }else if (ratings >= 3.00 && ratings < 3.50) {
                    binding.ratings.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E5DE21"))
                }
                else if (ratings >= 2.50 && ratings < 3.00) {
                    binding.ratings.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B18616"))
                }else if (ratings >= 2.00 && ratings < 2.50) {
                    binding.ratings.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFC225"))
                }else  {
                    binding.ratings.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF3F25"))
                }

                binding.editButton.setOnClickListener{
                    listener?.onDeleteButtonClicked(this)

                }
                binding.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener {
                    listener?.onEditButtonClicked(this)

                }
            }
        }
    }

    interface addedJobListAdapterClickListener{
        fun  onDeleteButtonClicked(allJobDetailsToShow: all_job_details_to_show)
        fun onEditButtonClicked(allJobDetailsToShow: all_job_details_to_show)
    }
}
```

My firebase database user_business is root and job is child and Job is parent of shown paramenters

[image: user_business is root and job is child and Job is parent of shown paramenters]

Also, user_business have other childs too:

[image: user_business have other childs too enter image description here]

here you can see

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If `databaseRef` is initialized as:

```
databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("user_business/$uid1")
```

So it points to the *child* node of the current user under `/user_business`. Then the first loop in here seems wrong:

```
databaseRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        mList.clear()
        for (taskSnapshot in snapshot.children){
            ....
            val jobDetails = taskSnapshot.child("Jobs")
            ....
```

If you look at the node at `/user_business/$uid`, by looping over the children as you do, your `taskSnapshot` will point to `Jobs` and there is no `Jobs/Jobs` in there.

My guess is that you want to do this instead:

```
databaseRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        mList.clear()
        for (taskSnapshot in snapshot.child("Jobs").children){
            ....
```

Comment: didn' work actually and also in adapter class my jobList things unable to call an instaces :(

Comment: First off: does the explanation at the start of my answer make sense? And do you agree that *could* explain why your code doesn't loop over the jobs? --- If so: can you be a bit clearer on precisely what didn't work? You might need to debug the problem locally, and tell us the results of that. So: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: If you're new to debugging like this in Android: The Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Comment: Thank you for support, my problem is sorted now...